# Android Studio "run" button is not working

Tags: android, android-studio

I have Android Studio 3.0.1 it was working fine until yesterday. Today when I just opened Android Studio, my "Run" button is not running application. It is green in color which means it is not disable, but still it is not doing any function on click. Why?

Comment: What run configuration is currently selected? (The drop-down list to the left of to the Run button)

Comment: @Michael Dodd app is selected...

Comment: `Clean` and `rebuild`  : is there some logs added ?

Comment: Have you tries the universal answer to all tech questions? Restsart studio, Restart computer.

Comment: @MominKhan And does the icon next to `app` have a little red x?

Comment: @HadjKhelil I did clean and rebuild: still same results not working.

Comment: @Aswin yes restarted studio now restarted my PC. Not working

Comment: @Michael everything is normal, there is no red cross icon, but not working.

Comment: can you put the screenshot of  toolbar.

Comment: Got similar issue after installing new Android Studio 3.1 Canary 6. Run starts app but uses old version instead of building it

Comment: I found the error, somehow adb.exe file was deleted from platform-tools folder and error was "Unable to locate adb java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate adb"

Just copy paste adb.exe file into platform-tools folder, and working now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the error, somehow ***adb.exe*** file was deleted from platform-tools folder and error was

> "Unable to locate adb java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to
>   locate adb"
>   .

Just copy paste ***adb.exe*** file into ***platform-tools*** folder, and working now.